# Drawing Lines with Angle

Tags: java, math, geometry, line, trigonometry

I'm writing a code for a game and I have 2 lines, Line A which I calculated it's length and angle and I have Line B whose x2 and y2 are gotten from line A and angle at which Line A is, my program works to some extent. It only works when the border sign is moved to NorthEast and SouthWest but doesn't work at NorthWest and SouthEast. Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Shapes");
        f.setSize(600, 300);
        f.setLocation(300, 300);
        f.setResizable(true);
        JPanel p = new JPanel() {
            int x2 = 250;
            int y2 = 175;

            //for line
            int x1 = 250;
            int y1 = 100;

            //Direction line x2 and y2
            int lastx2 = 250;
            int lasty2 = 1000;


            //Middle Positive Sign
            private Shape lineMp = null;
            private Shape lineMn = null;

            //Border Positive Sign
            private Shape lineBp = null;
            private Shape lineBn = null;

            //Line
            private Shape line = null;

            //Direction Line
            private Shape linelast = null;

            private Shape lineNorth = null;

            private Shape lineWest = null;


            {
                //North and South
                lineNorth = new Line2D.Double(250,1,250,470);

                lineWest = new Line2D.Double(1,175,470,175);
                //Middle positive
                lineMn = new Line2D.Double(235,175,265,175);
                lineMp = new Line2D.Double(250,160,250,190);

                //Border sign
                lineBn = new Line2D.Double(235,100,265,100);
                lineBp = new Line2D.Double(250,100,250,115);

                //Line
                line = new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,x2,y2);

                //Direction Line
                linelast = new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,lastx2,lasty2);


                MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
                    private Point prevPoint;
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        prevPoint = e.getPoint();
                        System.out.println("Prev Point=" + prevPoint.toString());
                        repaint();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                        int dx = 0;
                        int dy = 0;
                        dx = (int) (prevPoint.x - e.getPoint().getX());
                        dy = (int) (prevPoint.y - e.getPoint().getY());

                        //Middle Positive sign
                        Line2D shapeMn = (Line2D) lineMn;
                        Line2D shapeMp = (Line2D) lineMp;

                        //Border sign
                        Line2D shapeBn = (Line2D) lineBn;
                        Line2D shapeBp = (Line2D) lineBp;

                        //Line
                        Line2D shapeline = (Line2D) line;

                        //Direction Line
                        Line2D shapelastline = (Line2D) linelast;

                        int length = (int) Math.sqrt((shapeline.getY2() - shapeline.getY1()) * (shapeline.getY2() - shapeline.getY1()) + (shapeline.getX2() - shapeline.getX1()) * (shapeline.getX2() - shapeline.getX1()));
                        int angle = (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(Math.abs(shapeline.getY1() - shapeline.getY2()), Math.abs(shapeline.getX1() - shapeline.getX2())));



                        //Middle Positive sign
                        int nx1 = (int) (shapeMn.getX1() - dx);
                        int ny1 = (int) (shapeMn.getY1() - dy);

                        int nx2 = (int) (shapeMn.getX2() - dx);
                        int ny2 = (int) (shapeMn.getY2() - dy);

                        int px1 = (int) (shapeMp.getX1() - dx);
                        int py1 = (int) (shapeMp.getY1() - dy);

                        int px2 = (int) (shapeMp.getX2() - dx);
                        int py2 = (int) (shapeMp.getY2() - dy);

                        //Border sign
                        int Bnx1 = (int) (shapeBn.getX1() - dx);
                        int Bny1 = (int) (shapeBn.getY1() - dy);

                        int Bnx2 = (int) (shapeBn.getX2() - dx);
                        int Bny2 = (int) (shapeBn.getY2() - dy);

                        int Bpx1 = (int) (shapeBp.getX1() - dx);
                        int Bpy1 = (int) (shapeBp.getY1() - dy);

                        int Bpx2 = (int) (shapeBp.getX2() - dx);
                        int Bpy2 = (int) (shapeBp.getY2() - dy);

                        //Line
                        int x2 = (int) (shapeline.getX2() - dx);
                        int y2 = (int) (shapeline.getY2() - dy);

                        int ex1 = (int) (shapeline.getX1() - dx);
                        int ey1 = (int) (shapeline.getY1() - dy);

                        //Direction Line
                        int x1 = (int) (shapelastline.getX1() - dx);
                        int y1 = (int) (shapelastline.getY1() - dy);

                        int lastx2 = ((int) (shapelastline.getX1() - (length + 700) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))));
                        int lasty2 = ((int) (shapelastline.getY1() - (length + 700) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))));

                        int elastx2 = ((int) (shapelastline.getX1() - (length + 700) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))));
                        int elasty2 = ((int) (shapelastline.getY1() - (length + 700) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))));


                        Point startPointMn = new Point(nx1, ny1);
                        Point endPointMn = new Point(nx2, ny2);

                        Point startPointMp = new Point(px1, py1);
                        Point endPointMp = new Point(px2, py2);

                        Point startPointBn = new Point(Bnx1, Bny1);
                        Point endPointBn = new Point(Bnx2, Bny2);

                        Point startPointBp = new Point(Bpx1, Bpy1);
                        Point endPointBp = new Point(Bpx2, Bpy2);

                        Point startPoint = new Point((int)shapeline.getX1(), (int)shapeline.getY1());
                        Point endPoint = new Point(x2, y2);

                        Point estartPoint = new Point(ex1, ey1);
                        Point eendPoint = new Point((int)shapeline.getX2() , (int)shapeline.getY2());

                        //Start and End point of Direction line
                        Point StartLastPoint = new Point(x1, y1);
                        Point endLastPoint = new Point(lastx2, lasty2);

                        Point eendLastPoint = new Point(elastx2, elasty2);

                        GeneralPath Mp = new GeneralPath();
                        Mp.append(lineMn, false);
                        Mp.append(lineMp, false);

                        GeneralPath Bp = new GeneralPath();
                        Bp.append(lineBn, false);
                        Bp.append(lineBp, false);



                        if (Mp.getBounds().contains(prevPoint)) {
                            shapelastline.setLine(startPoint, eendLastPoint);
                            shapeline.setLine(startPoint,endPoint);
                            shapeMn.setLine(startPointMn, endPointMn);
                            shapeMp.setLine(startPointMp, endPointMp);
                            prevPoint = e.getPoint();
                            repaint();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (Bp.getBounds().contains(prevPoint)) {
                            shapelastline.setLine(StartLastPoint, endLastPoint);
                            shapeline.setLine(estartPoint, eendPoint);
                            shapeBn.setLine(startPointBn, endPointBn);
                            shapeBp.setLine(startPointBp, endPointBp);
                            prevPoint = e.getPoint();
                            repaint();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        repaint();
                    }
                };
                addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
                addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
            }
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setPaint(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.setStroke(new java.awt.BasicStroke(7));
                g2d.draw(lineBn);
                g2d.draw(lineBp);
                g2d.draw(lineMn);
                g2d.draw(lineMp);
            }

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                if (lineMn != null){
                    g2d.draw(linelast);
                    g2d.draw(line);
                    g2d.draw(lineNorth);
                    g2d.draw(lineWest);
                }
            }};
        f.add(p);
        p.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

This is where I set the x2 and y2 for line B:

```
int length = (int) Math.sqrt((shapeline.getY2() - shapeline.getY1()) * (shapeline.getY2() - shapeline.getY1()) + (shapeline.getX2() - shapeline.getX1()) * (shapeline.getX2() - shapeline.getX1()));
int angle = (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(Math.abs(shapeline.getY1() - shapeline.getY2()), Math.abs(shapeline.getX1() - shapeline.getX2())));


int lastx2 = ((int) (shapelastline.getX1() - (length + 700) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))));
int lasty2 = ((int) (shapelastline.getY1() - (length + 700) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))));
int elastx2 = ((int) (shapelastline.getX1() - (length + 700) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))));
int elasty2 = ((int) (shapelastline.getY1() - (length + 700) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))));
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working" is it displaying faulty or does the program crash, because this would help in finding the problem.

Comment: it does not display the way i want it to, it displays a straight line when it is on NorthWest or SouthEast

Comment: How should it be in the NW quadrant or SE quadrant? This cannot be clearly deduced from the behavior in the NE quadrant and SW quadrant. Example: In the NW quadrant, LineB could be deflected in the direction of the x-axis (i.e. symmetrical to the x-axis) or y-axis (i.e. symmetrical to the y-axis).

Comment: I want it to look like when it is on the x axis in the SW quadrant and y axis on the NE quadrant

Comment: Honestly, I still don't understand how it should be. On a hunch, try this: (1) Remove _both_ `Math.abs` in the equation for `angle` (i.e. take the sign into account). (2) Replace `angle` with `delta - angle` in the equations for `lastx2` and `lasty2`. (3) Define `int delta` beforehand and try the following values: `delta = 0;`, `delta = 180;` and for a phase shift `delta = angle < 0 ? 0 : 180;` (here NE and SW are identical to those in your code) or `delta = angle > 0 ? 0 : 180;` Among these configurations there might be a suitable one. Otherwise you could try other configurations.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works to some extent too, but I'm still trying to figure out the problem, more so I don't know why my angle only prints 0 to 90 degrees only, it never prints 90 to 180 nor 0 - 360